Existence of a sequence satisfying a certain inequality
This is a sub-post to the other question: Weak law of large numbers for weak $L^1$ random variables. As the last part of the argument presented in the OP there hinges on a somewhat loose intuition, the reason for this separate post is to isolate that specific part of the proof to check for correctness.
For the context, a scalar random variable ${X}$ is said to be in weak ${L^1}$ if one has
$\displaystyle \sup_{t>0} t {\bf P}(|X| \geq t) < \infty$.
Now, given an unsigned weak ${L^1}$ random variable $X$ that is not almost surely zero, with ${\bf E}X = \infty$, let $\mu(t) := {\bf E}X1_{X \leq t}$. As $X$ is not integrable, $\mu(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$. Can we assert the existence of a sequence $r(n)$ tending to infinity such that $\mu(nr(n))/r(n) \geq 1$ for large $n$?

Yes, it works even if $X$ changes signs but $\mathbb EX^+ = +\infty$ and $\mathbb EX^-$ is finite. Hint: Consider sequence $(n_m){m}$ defined inductively as $n_m = \inf{ k \ge n{m-1}: \forall_{j \ge k}\ \mu(j) \ge 2^m}$ (set $n_0 = 0$ for convenience). Try to construct $r$ to be constant on ${n_{m-1} + 1, n_{m-1}, ..., n_m}$.

@DominikKutek: Thank you, it appears that making $r$ an increasing step function with $1 \leq r(n_m) \leq 2^m$ works for this construction.
